# How to increase Jquery variable in each loop

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a category color function in functions.php file and I am assigning category color for every li element with this code:

```
$i = 0;
$color = get_term_meta( $menu_item->object_id, '_category_color', true );
$color = ( ! empty( $color ) ) ? "#{$color}" : '#fff';
$menu_list .= "\t\t\t\t\t". '<li id="'.$i .'"style="border-left:5px solid '.$color .';">
<a href="'. $url .'">'. $title .'</a></li>' ."\n";
$i++;
```

And I am trying to get every li's border-left-color and assign them as a background to that div but in this jquery code, $i is stopping in 1 . How can I make this as a loop for every li?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$i = 0;
var $c=$('.side-category ul li#'+$i).css("border-left-color");
$('.side-category ul li#'+$i).css("background", $c);
$i++;
});
```

Thank you for reading it!

Comment: You don't have any loop...

Comment: Yes, I am not good at jquery, and I couldnt make a loop :)How can I make this as a loop ?

Comment: You can't define the background color on the server because...?

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the code within document.ready with this :

```
$('.side-category ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).css("background", $(this).css("border-left-color"));
})
```

There is no need to add `$i` , `jQuery` has `each` function , so you can directly use that.

The each function will go through each `li` within `.side-category ul`

Comment: By the way, Is there a option to apply background-color when :hover to li element?

Comment: Yes , you have to bind that event with each li.Post a different question for that , I post the answer over there :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146685/discussion-between-solhan-and-vivek-doshi).